# How do I design a responsive slider like this website. Similar Plugin anyone?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I design a responsive slider like this one,

http://www.northlandscapes.com/

I want the picture cover the whole screen at all time, no matter what the size is for the browser and still look good (No over stretch or too small), like this website.

I can't figure out how to re-size and crop the picture like he did when re-sizing the browser.

I have tried the WoWSlider plugin and it doesn't have the functionality I want.
Can someone recommend some similar slider plugin if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: try bootstrap to design mobile responsive websites.it has different css classes to support different width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a custom script, but you can use [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) and add a left column with thumbnails just in the example. Depending on your skills, it will look like the example (or not). I have done it before and works fine, so give it a try